# How to create a Hostingprocess?

Tags: c#, .net

How can i create in C# a hosting-process? i want to start an application (hosted) and assign a debugger to it and retrieve data from it (values of watches)

Comment: Check out [CLR Managed Debugger sample](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19621)... Note that your question is likely too broad to bring answers...

Comment: The "Visual Studio Hosing Process" doesn't have much of anything to do with the debugger.  It is a custom CLR host to change security policy.  Which makes debugging easier.  The debugger works fine when you turn it off.  What do you *really* want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IPCs (InterProcess Communication)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).